# I am creating a metadata scrubber web app can anyone help me how can I remove metadata from images

Tags: javascript, node.js, metadata, metadata-extractor

I am trying to create a metadata scrubber web app,
I am capable of reading metadata and implementing it but I am not capable of removing metadata from images

I tried npm pakages but I didn't work I am finding a npm pakage or js libraries which will help me to remove metadata from images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.